# Symfony 2 form : new field type : datalist type

Tags: symfony

For a project for my engineering school, I have to create search engine with an autocomplete function that search songs in Spotify database from a web page.
For that purpose, I have created a new field type "datalist" that displays a choices list when the user press a letter in the field.

I have followed instructions of several web sites, creating a `datalistType` class that I put bottom here, and I added the service in `service.yml` file.

Despite, I have followed all the instructions, I have always this error :

> "Could not load type "datalist".

Here is the code:

```
// config.yml

twig: 
    debug: "%kernel.debug%" 
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%" 
    form_themes: 
        - 'AppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' 

form: 
    resources: - 'AppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

---

```
// AppBundle\Form\Type\datalistType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class datalistType extends AbstractType {

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(['choices']);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['choices'] = $options['choices'];
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'datalist';
    }   
}
```

---

```
// AppBundle\Controller\FormController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\Type\formType;
use AppBundle\Entity\countries;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class FormController extends Controller 
{
    public function formAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new formType());
        if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
        {
            $form->bind($this->get('request'));
            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {
                $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
                $country = new countries();
                $country->setName($form->getData()['title']);
                $em->persist($country);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Form:form.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));

    }
}
```

---

```
// AppBundle\FormType\formType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\datalistType;

class formType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $merde = new datalistType();
        $builder->add('title');
        $builder->add('ajouter', 'submit');
        $builder->add('alphabet', 'datalist'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of symfony are you using ? + post your code

Comment: Here is my code : 

services.yml :

# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
        
services:
    app.form.type.datalist:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\DatalistType
        tags:
            - { name: app.form.type.datalist, alias: datalist }

Comment: Version Symfony 2.8

Comment: I believe. I am just verifying

Comment: post your code into your question, its not readable as a comment

Comment: Symfony version 2.8.20

Comment: also,  use 'DatalistType::class'      as the formtype   not  'datalist'

Comment: Hi @aymar and welcome to StackOverflow! Before posting questions here, please read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. When asking questions, please provide us with your code. Do not post answers to your question unless it's actually *the real answer*. If you have been asked for more details regarding your questions - edit your question and add them there.

Comment: Having said that, could you please: 1. post your code in the question; 2. state your symfony version (in the question and not in the comments, as sometimes things tend to get lost if there are many comments); 3. post links to the examples/tutorials you are trying to make work.

Comment: I posted the code in answers. It is not visible ?

Comment: I changed 'datalist' for datalistType::class as you said and effectively the error message disappeared, but I can't always used the autocomplete function on the alphabet field.

Comment: Maybe that I forgot something about the fields.html.twig template ?